# Single word for 'to become known or famous'

Tags: single-word-requests

I want to describe  an event that through the years has become known or popular, like the celebration of, say, Holloween for instance. We could say that Holloween  became popular or (...) a long time ago.

Comment: Hallowe'en was popularised a long time ago

Comment: Why not just *celebrated*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Halloween has been **popularized** outside of North America

[1.     to make popular; make attractive to the general public
2.      to make or cause to become easily understandable or acceptable](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/popularized)

Comment: Outside North America, some of us use *popularised* :)

Answer (score 3):

Consider "[**catch on**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/catch%20on)," "[**take hold**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+hold)," and "[**take root**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/take+root)."

> Halloween **caught on** in America in the late 1880s.
>
> Halloween **caught on** in America as Irish immigrants escaped Ireland's 1846 
>   potato famine.
>
> During the Victorian Era, the celebration of Halloween [**took hold**](http://mollybrownbtl.wordpress.com/2010/10/21/halloween-traditions/) in America and many of today's customs were developed.
>
> When I read this article, I was quite happy to see Halloween has [**taken root**](http://en.ria.ru/culture/20101031/161155286.html) in Russia.

Comment: Just the right "flavor"!

Answer (score 1):

**Prominent**

> having a quality that thrusts itself into attention

A word I know through my Scottish boss is **kithe**.

> To make known; to manifest; to show; to declare.

And just a really common word we use for this is **emerge|emergent**.

> become known or apparent

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

**To spread:**

- to become widely seen or known;

The celebration of Holloween spread a long time ago.

Answer (score 0):

Notable.  Notoriety is a great descriptor, but obviously connotes being known or famous for something negative...

Answer (score 0):

**Renown:**

- a state of being widely acclaimed and highly honored.
- synonyms: fame, celebrity, notoriety.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the context, *coming into the limelight* may be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

**famed** could be considered in this context

Answer (score -1):

How about **memorable**

Hence we may use "Halloween became a memorable event a long time ago."